# Substitute Excel-Workbook reference for another

Tags: vba, excel, time-limit-exceeded

I have an Excel-Workbook, where we have an sheet where we consolidate data. Basically we link to other Excel-Workbooks. I wrote the following Macro, in order to update the path and filename. We cannot just update the whole link, since other parts need to reference the old path (and filename).

```
Sub neueDatei()

Dim Pfad As String, DateiName As String, DateiName_alt As String, h As String, formel As String
Dim tblRow As Long, test As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim IVsh As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Set IVsh = wb.Sheets("Input Vektor")

With IVsh
    Pfad = .Range("C3").Value 'set the path
    DateiName = .Range("C4").Value 'set the filename
    tblRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
End With

If Mid(Pfad, Len(Pfad) - 1, 1) <> "\" Then
    Pfad = Pfad & "\" 'append \ if necessary
End If

If Mid(Pfad, 1, 1) <> "'" Then
    Pfad = "'" & Pfad 'excel needs a quote at the start of the path.
End If

DateiName_alt = DateiName

'add brackets to the filename
If Mid(DateiName, 1, 1) <> "[" Then
    DateiName = "[" & DateiName 
    DateiName = DateiName & "]"
End If

'substitute the filenames
For i = 19 To tblRow
    If IVsh.Cells(i, 7).Value <> "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
    h = IVsh.Cells(i, 2).Formula
    If InStr(1, h, "[") > 0 Then
        IVsh.Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=" & Pfad & DateiName & Mid(h, InStr(1, h, "]") + 1)
    Else
        IVsh.Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=" & Pfad & DateiName_alt & Mid(h, InStr(1, h, "xlsx") + 4)
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The problem is, that the code runs relatively slow (a few minutes for only 2-3 thousand lines). Any suggestions, how I can speed this up?

Comment: Welcome to CR! Please [edit] your question title so that it summarizes the **purpose** of the code. Everyone on this site wants better, faster code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that the word *neue* has a meaning in whatever language is native to this, as it's not English. But that **i** at the end of the sub's name, what is that?

---

It's good practice to indent *all of your code* that way `Labels` will stick out as obvious.

---

You forgot to define `i`

When you don't define your variable, VBA will declare it as a *Variant*, which are [objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcxd6b8.aspx):

> Performance. A variable you declare with the Object type is flexible
>   enough to contain a reference to any object. However, when you invoke
>   a method or property on such a variable, you always incur late binding
>   (at run time). To force early binding (at compile time) and better
>   performance, declare the variable with a specific class name, or cast
>   it to the specific data type.

Always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

---

#### Naming Variables

> ```
> Dim Pfad As String, DateiName As String, DateiName_alt As String, h As String, formel As String
> Dim tblRow As Long, test As Long
> Dim wb As Workbook
> Dim IVsh As Worksheet
> ```

Your names leave something to be desired, even if I ignore what the names might be spelled after in whatever your native language is.

Give your variables *meaningful names*! It makes life easier on **you** when you go back to this project later on.

What do `pFad`, `h`, `test` and `IVsh` tell me about what they are? I'll assume `pFad` is something short for the equivalent of file path, so like `fpath`. Why not spell the whole thing? Characters are *free* - `filePath`

The two variables with `Date` in the name are strings. Maybe *Date* doesn't mean what it does in English, but again - what's that `i` there for?

You also never use `forme1` or `test`.

[Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names.

In English I'd end up with something like

```
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim alternateFileName As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim index As Long
dim tempString as String
```

My `tempString` might not be a good name for your `h` but your `h` doesn't tell me what it is.

Also, Worksheets have a `CodeName` property - View Properties window (<kbd>F4</kbd>) and the `(Name)` field (the one at the top) can be used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets("Input Vektor")` and instead just use `inputVektor`.

---

#### With block

You are just grabbing some values from a sheet here, but you're doing it one at a time. If you had more data, you'd be better off with an array

```
Dim fileData As Variant
filedata = inputVecktorSheet.Range("C3:C4")
```

Then you can just get the information out with `fileData(1)` or whatever. It's not a big deal in this case, but it could become one.

But, speaking of arrays

You could probably pull a lot of this into an array, but I'll leave that up to you.

---

#### For Next

> ```
> For i = 19 To tblRow
>     If IVsh.Cells(i, 7).Value <> "" Then
>         Exit For
>     End If
>     h = IVsh.Cells(i, 2).Formula
>     If InStr(1, h, "[") > 0 Then
>         IVsh.Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=" & Pfad & DateiName & Mid(h, InStr(1, h, "]") + 1)
>     Else
>         IVsh.Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=" & Pfad & DateiName_alt & Mid(h, InStr(1, h, "xlsx") + 4)
>     End If
> Next i
> ```

Let's ignore that you're doing this all on the sheet instead of an array. Your first `If` block can be shortened like

```
If inputVektorSheet.Cells(index, CHECK_ROW).Length > 0 Then Exit For
```

Oh, right, I made some constants. They are much easier to deal with

```
Const CHECK_ROW As Long = 7
Const FORMULA_ROW As Long = 2
Const START_BRACKET As String = "["
Const END_BRACKET As String = "]"
Const FORMULA_START As String = "="
Const EXCEL_FILE_EXTENTION As String = "xlsx"
Dim tempFormula As String
For index = 19 To tblRow
    filePath = FORMULA_START & filePath
    If inputVektorSheet.Cells(index, CHECK_ROW).Length > 0 Then Exit For
    tempString = inputVektorSheet.Cells(index, FORMULA_ROW).Formula
    If InStr(1, tempString, START_BRACKET) > 0 Then
        tempFormula = filePath & fileName & Mid(tempString, InStr(1, tempString, END_BRACKET) + 1)
    Else
        tempFormula = filePath & alternateFileName & Mid(tempString, InStr(1, tempString, EXCEL_FILE_EXTENTION) + 4)
    End If
    inputVektorSheet.Cells(index, FORMULA_ROW).Formula
Next i
```

But, why are you exiting the entire loop if you hit a blank cell? Shouldn't all the cells you target have a value? And if they don't, just stop everything? Might be better off with some error handling instead.

And, wait, what's this

> ```
> DateiName_alt = DateiName
> ```

So, that can be combined too?

```
 filePath = FORMULA_START & filePath & fileName
```

And you can get rid of the `_alt` variable. I don't actually see you use the `_alt` variable at all.

---

#### If Blocks

As I said, a lot of your blocks can be shortened to one line

```
If Mid(Pfad, Len(Pfad) - 1, 1) <> "\" Then Pfad = Pfad & "\"
If Mid(Pfad, 1, 1) <> "'" Then Pfad = "'" & Pfad
If Mid(DateiName, 1, 1) <> START_BRACKET Then DateiName = START_BRACKET & DateiName & END_BRACKET
```

---

Comments - ["code tell you how, comments tell you why"](http://blog.codinghorror.com/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why/). The code should speak for itself, if it needs a comment, it might need to be made more clear. If not, the comment should describe *why* you're doing something rather than *how* you're doing it. Here are a [few reasons](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/254979/125931) to avoid comments all together.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lengthy answer, I will have a look at all the links you provided and will certainly use some of your suggestions.

Comment: Putting everything in an array, modifying the array and then replacing the whole range at once with the array sped up the code from a few minutes to not even a second. Thanks a lot! I also included many of your other tips, in order to make it more readable. (Btw. the language is German)

Comment: I thought it might be German, but I didn't want to make an incorrect assumption. Glad the array worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `Application.Calculation = xlManual` where you turn updating off, and then turn it back to `xlAutomatic` at the end.

In addition, turn events off (and then on again): `Application.EnableEvents = False` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

I suspect that everytime you change a file name in a cell, the workbook tries to access the link and update the cell.

Small point - doesn't affect speed:

```
If Mid(DateiName, 1, 1) <> "[" Then
    DateiName = "[" & DateiName 
    DateiName = DateiName & "]"
End If
```

could be

```
If Mid(DateiName, 1, 1) <> "[" Then
    DateiName = "[" & DateiName & "]"
End If
```

Instead of `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`, you could use `ThisWorkbook` - it is a little more assertive if that is what you need. I don't have the context on how this function is used, so it may be called when another workbook is active.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that's slowing you down is the number of individual read/write operations. You're much better off reading/writing the data/formulas all at once; it's much faster to loop through an array than to loop through cells. This version should be substantially faster:

```
'Get array of values that you're checking for blanks
Dim checkBlanksArr As Variant
checkBlanksArr = IVsh.Range(IVsh.Cells(19, 7), IVsh.Cells(tblRow, 7)).Value

'Get array of existing formulas to modify
Dim formulaRng As Range
Dim formulaArr As Variant
Set formulaRng = IVsh.Range(IVsh.Cells(19, 2), IVsh.Cells(tblRow, 2))
formulaArr = formulaRng.Formula

'Edit formulas
Dim fText As String
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(formulaArr, 1) To UBound(formulaArr, 1)
    If checkBlanksArr(i, 1) = "" Then
        fText = formulaArr(i, 1)
        If InStr(fText, "[") > 0 Then
            formulaArr(i, 1) = "=" & Pfad & DateiName & Mid(fText, InStr(fText, "]") + 1)
        Else
            formulaArr(i, 1) = "=" & Pfad & DateiName_alt & Mid(fText, InStr(fText, "xlsx") + 4)
        End If
    Else
        'Exiting here seems odd to me, but I can't say for sure without seeing the worksheet
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'Write new formulas to range
formulaRng.Formula = formulaArr
```

EDIT: Just noticed in a comment on another answer that the OP ended up doing something like this, and it indeed made things much faster.